# Paint Bitmap Image in Java Applet

Tags: java, image, applet, awt, paint

How would you paint a bitmap image into a Java applet using the paint(Graphics g) method? I have tried various methods found on Google, but none of them work as they should. They always cause the Applet to load with a white screen whenever they even compile.

**Below is a a simplified version of my code with most of the graphics removed. When nothing I tried on Google warranted the wanted result, I removed the code that I tried to use to import a bitmap.**

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.applet.Applet;
public class Spooky extends Applet
{
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        setBackground(gray);
        g.fillOval(5,5,75,75);
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.fillOval(20,20,75,75);
    }
}
```

Comment: could you post your code?

Comment: @nio See code in edit.

Comment: could you please post more code, i think the error will be somewhere in the part that creates the window.

Comment: I've already post everything that's important. The only code that I removed is extra lines that paint ovals. My applet only has a `paint()` method. It doesn't use an `init()` method or anything of that sort, although I tried adding one whenever I attempted to import a bitmap.

Comment: So if you say you have a white background, I suggest drawing with a different color than white on it. Black would be a good example of a color that looks good on white…

Comment: @Holger Once again, I would like to remind you that in my actual applet I do have a set background color, but for demonstration purposes I have removed that line. Could we please get back to the issue at hand?

Comment: You didn’t say that before. And your posted code does not set a background color.

Comment: Since it is bothering people, I added a background to the applet code.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your experiences. For me the snippet above with trivial corrections (Color.gray) runs fine and shows all the colors.

Comment: As for the original question. Use either g.drawImage to draw a bitmap that you have loaded before or put it inside a label. I anyway would use JApplet and JLabel.

Comment: Okay, thank you for the help. I managed to get it working!